# Integrating .NET COM Components into WordPress Plugin Using PHP and Debugging Errors

Tags: php, .net, wordpress, xampp, com

`**I've created a small demo program in .NET(version 4.8) Class Library that include few simple function that I'm utilizing in PHP using COM. This php file is also integrated as a WordPress plugin, and I've employed Xampp for this purpose.**

`**.Net Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace COMDEMO
{
    [ComVisible(true)]

    public class Class1
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string GetMessage()
        {
            return "Hello from .NET COM Component!";
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string Messages()
        {
            return ".NET COM Component messages section";
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string PostMessages()
        {
            return ".NET COM Component PostMessage section";
        }

    }
}`
```

**Then, in developer command prompt for VS 2022 (run as administrative), I have pasted below code from CMD:**

`Register the Assembly for COM Interop:

```
Use the regasm.exe tool (provided by .NET) to register the generated DLL for COM
interop. Run this from the command line with administrative privileges.

D:\DEMO\COMDEMO\COMDEMO\bin\Debug>gacutil /i COMDEMO.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache

D:\DEMO\COMDEMO\COMDEMO\bin\Debug>regasm.exe /codebase COMDEMO.dll /tlb:COMDEMO.tlb
Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.8.9032.0
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.9032.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Types registered successfully
Assembly exported to 'D:\DEMO\COMDEMO\COMDEMO\bin\Debug\COMDEMO.tlb', and the type 
library was registered successfully`
```

**---> even moved the dot net dll file to where php plugin located `(C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\Account Credentials)`**

**php plugin file code:**

```
`<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: Donate Button
  Description: alert dotnet data.
  Version: 1.0
  Author: NPS
*/

function donate_script() {
 
    $dotNetObject = new COM("COMDEMO.Class1");     
     ///-------> above Line 11 as indicated by error

    $result = $dotNetObject->GetMessage();
    echo $result; 

    ob_start();
    ?>
        <button onclick="callAccountCredentialFunction()">Checkout</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var resultFromPHP = "<?php echo addslashes($result); ?>";
            function callAccountCredentialFunction() {
                // Call the sendDataToServer() function from the "Account Credential
                 Form" plugin.
                // sendDataToServer();

               alert(resultFromPHP);
            }

        </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();

}


function donate_script_shortcode() {
    return donate_script();
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'donate_script_shortcode');
add_shortcode('donate_button', 'donate_script_shortcode');

?> `
```

**After, restarting apache in Xammp, reactivating plugin in wordpress, I got error in Page stating:**

Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Failed to create COM object `COMDEMO.Class1': Class not registered in C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\Account Credentials\Donate.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\Account Credentials\Donate.php(11): com->__construct('COMDEMO.Class1') #1 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\Account Credentials\Donate.php(35): donate_script() #2 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(433): donate_script_shortcode('', '', 'donate_button') #3 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #4 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(273): preg_replace_callback('/\[(\[?)(donate...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[account_form]\n...') #5 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(324): do_shortcode('[account_form]\n...') #6 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters('[account_form]\n...', Array) #7 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\blocks\post-content.php(48): apply_filters('the_content', '<!-- wp:shortco...') #8 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-block.php(258): render_block_core_post_content(Array, '<!-- wp:shortco...', Object(WP_Block)) #9 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-block.php(244): WP_Block->render() #10 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\blocks.php(1484): WP_Block->render() #11 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\blocks.php(1522): render_block(Array) #12 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\block-template.php(260): do_blocks('<!-- wp:templat...') #13 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template-canvas.php(12): get_the_block_template_html() #14 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106): include('C:\Program File...') #15 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\Program File...') #16 C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17): require('C:\Program File...') #17 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\Account Credentials\Donate.php on line 11
There has been a critical error on this website.

Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.

`your text`

**I want to know the root cause and debug it.
**
.`Net Version --> 4.8 .PHP ---> 8.0.0 latest version (download latest xampp)  .Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.8.9032.0`

**Even Make Necessary as recommended by ChatGpt in `Xampp/php/php.ini` file: **

`com.allow_dcom = true   /// this line is uncommented extension=php_com_dotnet.dll   /// added this line`

Even check the registery:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZauQ.png)

Expecting to debug the error.
I've created a small demo program in .NET(version 4.8) Class Library that include few simple function that I'm utilizing in PHP using COM. This php file is also integrated as a WordPress plugin, and I've employed Xampp for this purpose.`

Comment: Have you tried using https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php? Note that you need PHP 8 or above

Comment: There could be a mismatch between the architecture of the PHP interpreter (32-bit or 64-bit) and your .NET assembly. Ensure that both are either 32-bit or 64-bit. For instance, if you're using a 64-bit version of PHP, your .NET assembly should also be compiled in 64-bit mode.